# Posts after the first one are shown as columns

Tags: templates, articles

So well, I have an issue with an artisteer theme, or so I thought. The problem lies within Joomla because using other themes results in the same outcome.
Please look at [TKMS.si](http://tkms.si), so you'll know what I mean.

I inspected the problem and noticed there are problems with the classes added to the posts.

```
<div class="item column-1">[...]</div>
```

This is the wrapper div of the second post.
I removed column-1 from the class:

```
<div class="item">[...]</div>
```

And now it works flawlessly, but how can I change it on the server so it stays like this? (I was only using Chromiums Inspect Element)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I found the article manager options and there I found Blog /featured layouts and I changed the number of leading elements and links to 5 and others I changed to 0. Still there is no change. What to do?

Comment: This is something that's generated in the functions.php or the index.php file within your template folder. I would strongly recommend using a non-artisteer template as they are simply (excuse my french, but...) crap

Comment: Yeah I know, but I have been told that I must use this.
It's not the themes fault I am sure, because other themes have the same problem.

Comment: I did find what I've been looking for. The problem was in the menu entry where the numbers I mentioned in my EDIT are also written. I left the fields blank and the global settings applied.

Comment: Default Joomla themes do not use `column-1 `anywhere so this must be a default class that Artisteer uses

Comment: Open the menu item and look at the layout settings there as well for leading articles and columns.

Comment: Have you disabled cache?

Answer (score 1):

When you changed the article options, you only changed the global defaults

Open up your menu manager
Edit the menu ITEM
Go into (blog) layout settings and you will find the options for Intro Articles, columns etc

Make the change here and you should now see results. Ironically if you leave these fields blank global defaults are used, but I think by default they are NOT blank and pull in the global default settings.. hence the global configuration will not work.. which is just damned annoying!

No need to make any code changes for this fix at all